# Hyundai Accent mysteriously stopped starting

Tags: battery, starter, sensor

Just bought an 08 accent with 132 kkm a few weeks ago. Ran great until I drove it home one night and the next morning it wouldn't start. The starter spun but didn't engage flywheel so naturally I bought a new/remanufactured starter and installed it to the same results. I've boosted the battery and pushed the car in fourth gear to try and engage it. Flywheel and old starter teeth seemed fine and never missed. Error codes say camshaft sensor. Looked at timing belt and its fine.

Any help would be great. I'm going to pull the pain in the *#( to remove starter again tomorrow and bench test it to make sure.

EDIT:

I bench tested the starter two days ago and got another then installed it and am still having no luck. The starter spins but does not engage. Any help would be great as I live 60km from the city and it would be a large tow bill.

Comment: Evidently the starter is bad or there are teeth missing on the flywheel, rotate the engine manually to see if you can get past the bad spot on the flywheel, then try starting, if it engages then you have a bad flywheel.

Comment: Did thanks the flywheel is in good shape. I've also pushed it in 3rd and 4th gear about 40 feet to no avail. It's also the third starter I've tried in it. I'm kind of lost and regret buying this tiny car.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Does the car bump / push start?

Comment: There is a lot of reasons as to why your car stops, mine is because of a dead battery. After replacing it it works again, it will be best if you have it check from time to time to avoid further complications.